# Mongodb embedded timedout for Spring unit test

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to test a mongo db repository using flapdoodle embed mongo, my test looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.mongodb.embedded.version=5.0.6")
public class TaskToDoRepositoryAdapterTest {

    @Autowired
    private TaskToDoRepositoryAdapter adapter;

    private final TaskToDo task1 = TaskToDo.builder().id("1").name("Task 1").description("Task Desc 1").assignedUserId("56").build();
    private final TaskToDo task2 = TaskToDo.builder().id("2").name("Task 2").description("Task Desc 2").assignedUserId("56").build();
    private final TaskToDo task3 = TaskToDo.builder().id("3").name("Task 3").description("Task Desc 3").assignedUserId("57").build();
    private final TaskToDo task4 = TaskToDo.builder().id("4").name("Task 4").description("Task Desc 4").assignedUserId("56").done(true).build();

    @BeforeEach
    public void saveInitialData() {
        final Mono<Void> result = adapter.saveAll(just(task1, task2, task3, task4));
        StepVerifier.create(result).verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFindAll() {
        StepVerifier.create(adapter.findAll().collectList())
            .assertNext(tasks -> assertThat(tasks).contains(task1, task2, task3, task4)).verifyComplete();
    }


    @Test
    public void findAllUserOpenTasks() {
        final Flux<TaskToDo> openTasks = adapter.findAllUserOpenTasks("56");
        StepVerifier.create(openTasks.collectList()).assertNext(tasks ->
            assertThat(tasks).containsOnly(task1, task2))
            .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

and my gradle dependencies includes spring data mongodb and flapdoodle embed mongo:

```
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:2.7.0"
 testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.4.6'
```

When I run my test, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onError(org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:52130, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:52130, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException}}]))
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failPrefix(MessageFormatter.java:104)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.fail(MessageFormatter.java:73)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failOptional(MessageFormatter.java:88)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.lambda$expectComplete$4(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:336)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$SignalEvent.test(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:2218)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignal(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1490)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1438)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1091)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:84)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredError(FluxUsingWhen.java:398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$RollbackInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:475)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:364)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:842)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:863)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:990)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:545)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.OperationExecutorImpl.lambda$execute$9(OperationExecutorImpl.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$exceptionTransformingCallback$23(CommandOperationHelper.java:632)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier$RetryingCallback.onResult(RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier.java:109)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withAsyncSuppliedResource$7(OperationHelper.java:649)
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$2.onResult(AsyncClusterBinding.java:151)
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$2.onResult(AsyncClusterBinding.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster$ServerSelectionRequest.onResult(BaseCluster.java:449)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.handleServerSelectionRequest(BaseCluster.java:320)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.access$700(BaseCluster.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster$WaitQueueHandler.run(BaseCluster.java:499)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:52130, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:52130, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException}}]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:95)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:2954)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.lambda$translateException$89(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:2937)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3733)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:52130, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException}}]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:424)
```

Did anybody know what I'm doing wrong?, I can't figure out why this is happening

Regards